# In book class, fancy page heading stumbles with Preface

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, front-matter

Thanks, Werner, your suggestion worked nicely. I here provide a minimalist example that works

In book class, I define headers and have a Preface:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 
\usepackage{lipsum,layout,fancyhdr}
\let\oldchaptermark\chaptermark% Store \chaptermark % added to cut
\pagestyle{fancy} % read package doc. 
\let\chaptermark\oldchaptermark% Restore \chaptermark % added to restore
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{<Historical Materialism>}} %
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage} %
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage} %
\begin{document} %
\frontmatter \chapter{Preface}
\lipsum
\mainmatter 
\chapter*{Chapter}
\backmatter 
\end{document}
```

Now the Preface header is just "Preface"

Comment: Could you post   a minimal compilable code?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem here is. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s `fancy` page style redefines `\chaptermark` - the macro responsible for storing content in the page marks.

Here's the original definition of `\chaptermark` when you just load the `book` class *without `fancyhdr`:

```
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
      \fi
    \fi
    #1}}{}}%
```

Note how it conditions on whether you're in the `\mainmatter` or not - `\ifmainmatter` ... `\fi`. Here's the definition when you load `fancyhdr` and execute `\pagestyle{fancy}`:

```
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
      \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
    \fi
    #1}}{}}%
```

There's no conditioning on the existence of `\mainmatter`.

A solution is to store `\chaptermark` before `\pagestyle{fancy}` and restore it afterwards:

```
\let\oldchaptermark\chaptermark% Store \chaptermark
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\chaptermark\oldchaptermark% Restore \chaptermark
```